# Ubuntu 22.04.4 sound: humming while nothing is playing

Tags: sound

When no sound is being played a slightly audible hum is being emitted by the speakers (aux connection). The hum is not present while audio is being played, even if there is currently no sound, for example in a silent bit in a movie. Once playback stops the humming will return within a couple of seconds. Otherwise audio is working fine.

I do realize this can have a multitude of hardware/location related causes, which I tried to rule out by: connecting the speaker to two other workstations (win10, ubuntu 22.04.4), changing speaker location away from other devices and checking the aux cable for any visible faults.

What leads me to ask for help here is that the humming seizes when I have Settings->Sound opened but returns once I navigate away. I am assuming some kind of empty signal is send to the speaker while on Settings->Sound and was hoping this could somehow be made permanent.

I have little knowledge of how to configure audio devices in general. All settings/drivers have been left vanilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was eventually fixed by a recent update.